# Sometimes this script fails to update the iptables

Tags: iptables, spam

It does not happen often, but sometimes after running the below script, checking the iptables with `service iptables status` shows that they weren't updated and the script doesn't output any error.

The iptables is structured as look-up tree (long repeated sections snipped):

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -F
iptables -X 
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s 93.225.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 15.102.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 47.122.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT

iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-0
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-1
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-2
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-3
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-4
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-5
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-6
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-7
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-8
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-9
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-10
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-11
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-12
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-13
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-14
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-15
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-16
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-17
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-18
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-19
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-20
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-21
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-22
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-23
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-24
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-25
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-26
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-27
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-28
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-29 
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-30
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-31
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-32
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-33
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-34
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-35
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-36
iptables -N MY_CHAIN_L1-37

iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 1.54.96.0-5.133.179.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-0
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 5.133.180.0-24.113.159.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-1
[snip]
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 195.13.45.0-198.11.255.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-29 
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 198.12.64.0-199.19.215.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-30
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 199.21.96.0-200.31.3.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-31
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 200.31.11.0-202.171.255.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-32
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 203.130.134.192-206.212.255.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-33
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 206.214.64.0-211.155.95.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-34
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 212.19.128.0-216.176.191.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-35
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 216.189.0.0-218.23.255.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-36
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 218.30.96.0-223.255.231.255 -j MY_CHAIN_L1-37

iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-0 -s 1.54.96.0/20 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-0 -s 1.208.0.0/12 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-0 -s 1.224.0.0/11 -j DROP
[snip]
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-0 -s 5.133.178.0/23 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-0 -j ACCEPT


iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-1 -s 5.133.180.0/22 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-1 -s 5.135.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-1 -s 5.153.232.0/21 -j DROP
[snip]
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-1 -s 24.113.128.0/19 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-1 -j ACCEPT

.
.
.

iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.13.45.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.20.224.0/19 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.31.216.0/26 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.58.245.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.60.164.0/23 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.60.240.0/22 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.62.10.0/23 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.110.30.0/23 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.154.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.190.13.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-29 -s 195.211.152.0/22 -j DROP 
iptables -A MY_CHAIN_L1-1 -j ACCEPT

[snip more of same to end of script]
```

Can anyone see why this script would silently fail to update the iptables *sometimes*?  Maybe it's not the script?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are so many other things wrong with this script. The naming conventions are terrible. How is anybody going to remember what those rule names mean?

If this is generated code, the naming is not as important, but the names should still be structured in a way that makes it possible to understand, what the chain is supposed to do.

I'm thinking you might be able to simply use netmasks instead of the `iprange` module.

Additionally, I don't think it is a good idea to run so many separate `iptables` commands. I'd rather recommend you pipe the entire rule set into `iptables-restore`, such that you don't have to worry about what happens to packets being processed in between the `iptables` commands. That change might also fix your problem with the updates not always getting applied.

Comment: Gee whiz, I'm surprised you are so harsh and yet can't even understand what it does.  Yes, it is generated code, and yes, I understand what the logic part of it does perfectly; why not you smarty pants?

Comment: AlJo, be a little less sensitive.  kasperd is no idiot, and for what it's worth, I agree with his criticisms: you're using the wrong tool to set a hugely over-complex ruleset.  Here on ServerFault, it's OK for someone to suggest that you may be causing yourself most of the problems you're experiencing because of the highly non-standard way you're doing something.